# WP Facebbok Login - errors while loading page

Tags: wordpress, facebook-login

I really do not know the advice. No facebook application settings work.

```
Thank you

XMM-b79-1BK.js:44 Uncaught Error: Minified exception occurred; use the non-minified dev environment for the full error message and additional helpful warnings.
    at a (XMM-b79-1BK.js:44)
    at a (XMM-b79-1BK.js:121)
    at x (XMM-b79-1BK.js:193)
    at Object.b.post [as log] (XMM-b79-1BK.js:193)
    at a.logVital (XMM-b79-1BK.js:219)
    at XMM-b79-1BK.js:293
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at IntersectionObserver.f.threshold (XMM-b79-1BK.js:293)
```

Comment: You should start by posting the error message from the non minified javascript file

Answer (score 1):

It is a known bug, you can subscribe here: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1337180213092053/

Comment: thank you, maybe it will be repaired soon. It's special that another site with the same plug-in does not happen.